# R - number of patients recovering from the dataset

Tags: r

```
df <- read.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ulklc/covid19- 
    timeseries/master/countryReport/raw/rawReport.csv')
df$countryName = as.character(df$countryName)
df$countryName[df$countryName == "United States"] <- "United States of America"
```

within countries Find the dates when the number of recovered has passed confirmation.

as output ;

```
day 

''  day              countryName        confirmed     recovered 
''  2020/04/10         Spain              1500          1550
''  2020/01/19         italy              862            900
...
```

Comment: Do you need the first day or all days per country?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `base R`:

```r
df[df$confirmed <= df$recovered,]
```

Using `dplyr`:

```r
df %>%
  filter(confirmed <= recovered)
```